# How to register a component locally?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using `vue-cli 2.8.1.` and the project initiated with `vue init webpack project`.

I'm trying to register `AppButton` locally (like in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration)), but get an error:

> Unknown custom element: app-button - did you register the component
> correctly?

---

**main.js**

```
import Vue           from 'vue'
import AppComponent  from '@/components/app/app.component.vue'
import AppButton     from '@/components/button/button.component.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<AppComponent/>',
  components: {AppComponent, AppButton}
})
```

**app.component.vue**

```
<template src="./app.component.html"></template>
<script src="./app.component.js"></script>
<style src="./app.component.css"></style>
```

**button.component.vue**

```
<template src="./button.component.html"></template>
<script src="./button.component.js"></script>
<style src="./button.component.css"></style>
```

---

Everything works as expected if I register `AppButton` component globally, but I don't want to repeat `Vue.component('app-button', AppButton)` for every component. What would you recommend in this case?

```
import Vue           from 'vue'
import AppComponent  from '@/components/app/app.component.vue'
import AppButton     from '@/components/button/button.component.vue'

Vue.component('app-button', AppButton)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<AppComponent/>',
  components: {AppComponent}
})
```

Comment: Where is the script where you register it locally?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/64/ this is an example of local components registration. Compare it to your failed solution, you've probably missed something. The same schema applies to nested components inside other components: import & declare inside `components` section.

Comment: @BertEvans, sorry, I messed up the code a bit. Now that I've edited it the script where I register the component locally is the top one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register it globally in `main.js`, then you will not have to register it in each of your components. It will just be globally available.

Your first example only makes the AppButton available in the root scope. It does not make it available in any descendant scopes. That's why you run into the error.